# How to remotely add term sets in the central administration term store using C# or Powershell

Tags: development, powershell, managed-metadata

I would like to add remotely term sets in the managed metada service using C# or Powershell.
How can I do it ?

Regards,

Arioule

Answer (score 0):

```
   $GroupName="GroupName"
   $TermSet="TermSet"

   $taxonomySite =get-SPSite "SiteURL"
   $taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -site $taxonomySite
   $termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["MMD Service Name"]
   write-host "Connection made with term store -"$termStore.Name

   $termGroup=$termStore.Groups[$GroupName]

   $termSet_AS = $group.CreateTermSet($TermSet)
   $termSet_AS.IsOpenForTermCreation = $true;
   $termStore.CommitAll()


   $trmSet = $termGroup.TermSets[$TermSet]
   $term = $trmSet.CreateTerm($termName, 1033) 
   $termStore.CommitAll()
```